# How to create an array of numbers prefixed with 0 using str_pad()?

Tags: php

How can I generate an array of numbers using `str_pad()`?

For example, from `000` to `090` or from `100` to `200`.

```php
    $n2 = str_pad($n + 1, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

The above just adds `1` to `$n`.

I want to create an array using this method. For example: `000, 001, 002, 003, 004 ...`

For my requirements, numbers start at 000 and not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, using [range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php). Basically just loop through the range and pad each number as you go. There may be more direct ways but this is a simple approach:

```
$arr = [];

foreach (range(0, 90) as $n)
{
    $arr[] = str_pad($n, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

var_export($arr);
```